# Get xml web service request

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm submitting a request to a web service, but I'm receiving some errors.  They've asked to see an example of the xml request and response.  I used Visual Studio to consume the web service, so I'm just calling a method in my code - I don't actually see any xml.

Is there a way to grab the XML request and response as XML or at least a text string?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Web Reference or a Service Reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using a 3rd party tool, like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) . You'll be glad you started using this tool anyway.

Comment: Have you done this before?  I'm reading tutorials (most of them outdated) but they're not helping.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get that working for web service requests.  I ended up writing some code using XmlSerializer to output an xml file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly do you mean by "couldn't get that working"? Basically all there is to it is 1. Fire up fiddler 2. Whatch the requests getting logged. I assume no requests showed up?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Matthieu, dude, that's like asking, `where to download google chrome from?` and provide an answer pointing to `http://google.com` and you are telling me to provide more description? Come on, be serious.

Answer (score 0):

I had to debug what was going across the line recently and tools like wireshark and fiddler are great tools for debugging the request and response unless you are using HTTPS or you are debugging on your local machine and executing the client and the web service locally.

I found a method that allows you to see the details of both the request and response without having to modify a single line of your code.

.NET has a feature built in called tracing. By enabling tracing for the System.NET namespace you can capture everything.

Here are the steps to enable.

Add the following code to your app.config in your client applications.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true"  />
<sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
            <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
    </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
    <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now when you execute your client application you can go into the folder that your executable was run from and find the file System.Net.trace.log

You will then find in the log file your request and the servers response. The great thing about this solution is you do not have to install or run anything extra. However the solution is probably only a solution for developing or diagnosing something in test or stage environment rather than production. However I am assuming because you mention creating the solution in Visual Studio and it not working that you are clearly in the development stage.

Comment: Unfortunately it's only capturing the first 1024 characters :(